# Openmp 'shared’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp

Tags: c, openmp

Hi i am getting a weird error

```
#include <omp.h>
#define N 1000

main ()
{

int i, nthreads;
int chunk = 10;
float a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N];
double result =0;

#pragma omp parallel 
{

nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
printf("no of threads %d", nthreads);

#pragma omp for  shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i)  schedule(static,chunk) // line 18
for (i=0; i < N; i++){
  a[i] = i * 1.5;
  b[i] = i + 22.35;
}

#pragma omp barrier

#pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk) shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i)  reduction(+:result)   // line 26
for(i=0; i < N; i++){
result = result + (a[i]+b[i]);
}

}
printf("value is %f", result);

}
```

According to openmp pragma for rules , shared is allowed, but here iam getting a compile error simply because iam using shared here. Could someone please help me out.

```
test2.c:18: error: ‘shared’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp for’
test2.c:26: error: ‘shared’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp for’
```

Comment: `shared` is allowed for `omp for`? Where do you get this? According to this doc, `shared` is not listed as available.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_for.html

Comment: so then only parallel "pragma omp parallel for" allows shared ?

Comment: Yes - clauses describing variable sharing are associated with the parallel region, not the worksharing constructs within the parallel region.  So you put them on the #pragma omp parallel line, not the #pragma omp for line.   You can help yourself by defining variables locally inside the parallel block; those are all then private.

Comment: Thanks for @JonathanDursi 's clarification, resolving my confusion, too.

Comment: could one of you write a answer so that i can award points

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to your question, I do understand the fixed code should be like:

```
#include <omp.h>
#define N 1000

main ()
{

    int i, nthreads;
    int chunk = 10;
    float a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N];
    double result =0;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i)
    {

        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("no of threads %d", nthreads);

        #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk) // line 18
        for (i=0; i < N; i++){
          a[i] = i * 1.5;
          b[i] = i + 22.35;
        }

        #pragma omp barrier

        #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk) reduction(+:result)   // line 26
        for(i=0; i < N; i++){
            result = result + (a[i]+b[i]);
        }

    }
    printf("value is %f", result);

}
```